# Python - if statement inside while loop not responding

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I'm having trouble with an if statement inside a while loop.

```
while pressed == 8 :
    print(answerlistx[randomimage], answerlisty[randomimage])
    entryx = e1.get()
    entryy = e2.get()
    answerx = answerlistx[randomimage]
    answery = answerlisty[randomimage]
    print(entryx, entryy)
    if e1 == answerx and e2 == answery:
        print("correct")
        canvas.delete(images)
        randomimage = random.randrange(0,49+1)
        scorecounter = scorecounter + 1
        game = PhotoImage(file=imagelist[randomimage])
        images = canvas.create_image(30, 65, image = game, anchor = NW)
        e1.delete(0, END)   
        e2.delete(0, END)
        pressed = ''
    else:
        print("incorrect")
        e1.delete(0, END)   
        e2.delete(0, END)
        pressed = ''
```

The while loop is supposed to check to see if the inputs from the entry widget match the the answer but even when the answer is correct it goes to the else statement. I have 2 print statements just before the if statement which prints the input and what the answer is just incase it didn't have that but it does display it both correctly. I also thought it might have been a mix up with strings and integers so I changed all the answers in the answerlist to strings with no luck.
Anyone able to figure out what is wrong with it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use common sense. If it goes to `else`, `e1 == answerx and e2 == answery` is not true. PERIOD. now, figure out why. Have you checked what the type and value of those variables? some trace messages can do miracles...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The OP says "even when the answer is correct it goes to the else statement".

Comment: Just an observation from looking at the code but are you sure you are not meant to be comparing `entryx` and `entryy` with `answerx` and `answery`? as this is what you are printing before the comparison. Currently you are comparing `e1` and `e2` which you are not printing for visual validation.

Comment: @Haidro: I trust the python compiler/runtime. I don't trust the OP. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath That's not very nice tbh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are testing if the *entry objects* are the same as the answers. Use the actual values:

```
if entryx == answerx and entryy == answery:
```

instead of testing against `e1` and `e2`.

Comment: As it stands this is just speculation although I suspect this is the correct answer.

Comment: Yep, it's correct, but it's telling me I can't accept the answer yet and thanks heaps for the answer Martijn Pieters!

Comment: Glad to have been of help! @justinfay: it was a little more than just speculation. :-)